# Pug / Express - ng-for equivalent

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

I have an html page written with pug.js.

It contains one input and a table of *n* lines.

I would like *n* to be the number written by the user in the input.

If the user changes the input, the number of lines should auto adjust live.

How can I do that without using Angular ? It seems that Pug can't do this and I can't find other tools.

Thanks

Comment: Pug runs on server and user interaction will take place on browser side, so Pug cannot do this. But this can be simply done using Javascript or jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In your opinion, what would be the most elegant way to code it?

Comment: Can you use jQuery or you need JavaScript only solution?

Comment: jquery is the easier and most readable way in my opinion, but it adds a dependency in your project, javascript would be more verbose, but would do the job.

Comment: I can use JQuery.